# 'new char[]' does not work, but it should

Tags: c++, object, pointers, memory, return

I had the code, that returned char*
If a write in cpp:

```
char* test_char = new char[size];
```

all is good, but if i write in header:

```
char* test_char;
```

and in cpp:

```
test_char = new char[size];
```

the program compiles but does not run.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean "does not run"?

Comment: Show us the code in your header and in cpp file.

Comment: Can you post a "complete" piece of code, rather than just a couple of lines? It's hard to understand exactly how they connect together, which may well be where the problem is. (I edited to format what code you posted, but I didn't fix the "obvious" typo of `char = new char[size]`, as I'm not 100% sure what that is meant to do)

Comment: "the program compiles"  No, it doesn't.  Not as posted, anyway.

Comment: If you write `char = new char[size];`, the code certainly won't compile.

Comment: I mean: test_char = new char[size];

Answer (score 5):

> char = new char[size];

You probably want

```
test_char = new char[size];
```

Comment: Yes, this is what was meant

Answer (score 3):

```
char = new char[size];
```

This should not even compile.  You are missing a variable name:

```
test_char = new char[size];
```